# Replace a value in a Df based in 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace a value in a Df based on 2 conditions and doesn´t seem to work. I have tried 2 different options:
I want to replace a certain value of the column named "Debt"

```
Df[(Df['time_idx'] ==82) & (Df['Country'] == "France") ]["Debt"]=7

Df.iloc[0]["Debt"]=7
```

Any ideas of why it does not work? It doesn´t give an error but the value doesn´t change

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You're modifying a copy of the dataframe, thus the original dataframe remains unchanged.

Use `loc`:

```
Df.loc[(Df['time_idx'] ==82) & (Df['Country'] == "France"), "Debt"]=7
```

Answer (score 1):

example dataframe

```
    Name  Age
0    Tom   20
1   nick   21
2  krish   19
3   jack   18
```

reason why your code doesn't work is you are making changes to a sliced part as this code which returns this

```
df[(df['Age']==20) & (df['Name']=='Tom')]

output:

  Name  Age
0  Tom   20
```

and setting value using slice is not posssible and returns this warning

```
'''A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead'''
```

you can simply use .loc for accomplishing this

```
df.loc[((df['Age']==20) & (df['Name']=='Tom')),'Age']=9
    Name  Age
0    Tom    9
1   nick   21
2  krish   19
3   jack   18
```

and in your case it is

```
Df.loc[(Df['time_idx'] ==82) & (Df['Country'] == "France"), "Debt"]=7
```

Comment: Do accept the solution you found helpful and informative